# inserting column names into table

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table name that I am pulling the column names from is `dbcrms.sourcedata`. I am trying to pull all the column names and insert them into a table called `data_columns`. How would I do so? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really knowing your full table schema here is an example of what you can do using [information_schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql):

```
INSERT INTO data_columns  (column_name)
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'sourcedata' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbcrms';
```

Comment: tried this but it only returned a blank column with no results.     SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'dbcrms.report.ssrs_sourcedata'

Comment: You've added the schema to your table name, just do ssrs_sourcedata and see what you get